# count rows using three tables

Tags: mysql, join

I've three mysql database tables as

```
 1) websites
+-----+--------------------+
|  id |website             |
+-----+--------------------+
|   1 | http://abcd.com    |
|   2 | http://xyz.com     |
|   3 | http://pqrs.com    | 
+-----+--------------------+

 2) pages
+-----+---------------------------------------+
|  id |page                                   |
+-----+---------------------------------------+
|   1 | http://abcd.com/index.php             |
|   2 | http://abcd.com/contact.php           |
|   3 | http://xyz.com /index.php             | 
|   4 | http://pqrs.com /index.php            |
+-----+---------------------------------------+

 3) statistics
+-----+-------------------+
|  id |page_id | type     |
+-----+-------------------+
|   1 | 1      | AOL      |
|   2 | 1      | YAHOO    |
|   3 | 2      | AOL      | 
|   4 | 3      | YAHOO    |
|   5 | 3      | YAHOO    |
|   6 | 4      | YAHOO    |
+-----+-------------------+
```

I want OUTPUT as:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+
|website            | count_hit_by_AOL   | 
+-------------------+--------------------+
|http://abcd.com    |      2             |
|http://xyz.com     |      0             |
|http://pqrs.com    |      0             |
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

For getting this output I'm using following mysql query--

```
SELECT
  COUNT(statistics.id) as count_stats,
  websites.website
FROM websites,
  pages,
  statistics
WHERE pages.page LIKE CONCAT(websites.website,'%')
    AND pages.id = statistics.page_id
    and statistics.type LIKE 'AOL%'
GROUP BY websites.website
ORDER BY count_stats DESC
```

and I'm getting output as

```
+-------------------+--------------------+
|website            | count_hit_by_AOL   | 
+-------------------+--------------------+
|http://abcd.com    |      2             |
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Please help me if I'm doing anything wrong because I'm new in MYSQL.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with you existing query is you are using an `INNER JOIN` on the tables so you will only return the rows that match.

Since you want to return all `website` rows, then you will want to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT w.website, count(s.id) Total
FROM websites w
LEFT JOIN pages p
  on p.page like CONCAT(w.website,'%')
LEFT JOIN statistics  s
  on p.id = s.page_id
  and s.type like 'AOL%'
group by w.website
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78c13/7). The result is:

```
|         WEBSITE | TOTAL |
---------------------------
| http://abcd.com |     2 |
| http://pqrs.com |     0 |
|  http://xyz.com |     0 |
```

Edit #1, if you want to include the total number of pages per website, then you can use:

```
SELECT w.website, 
  count(s.id) TotalStats,
  count(p.page) TotalPages
FROM websites w
LEFT JOIN pages p
  on p.page like  CONCAT (w.website,'%')
LEFT JOIN statistics  s
  on p.id = s.page_id
  and s.type like 'AOL%'
group by w.website
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78c13/9). The result of this query is:

```
|         WEBSITE | TOTALSTATS | TOTALPAGES |
---------------------------------------------
| http://abcd.com |          2 |          2 |
| http://pqrs.com |          0 |          1 |
|  http://xyz.com |          0 |          1 |
```

Comment: Thank you its working. Can i get the number of pages in each website with the same query?

Comment: @VandanaPareek See my edit, that includes the total number of pages per site as well.